Harmonic map in the homotopy class of the identity map
Eells and Sampson's existence Theorem states that if $(N, h)$ is nonpositively curved, then a given map $f : (M, h') \to (N, h)$ can be deformed into a harmonic map in its homotopy class. Here smooth manifolds are closed, connected and oriented.
Now, let $(X, g_h)$ be a closed hyperbolic manifold, and let $g$ be a smooth Riemannian metric on $X$. Does there always exist a harmonic map in the homotopy class of $\text{Id}: (X, g_h) \to (X, g)$?
